# Does git push all local commits after rebase?

Tags: git, git-push

Let's assume two scenarios:

1. **Working directly on the shared developer branch**: Does a push after a rebase also transmit all commits that have been made before this rebase?
2. **Working in a separate test-branch & merge into developer branch**: Does a push of the developer branch after a rebase also transmit all commits that have been made before the rebase and the subsequent merge (test->developer) even if fast-forward mode?

Answer (score 3):

[Schleis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19959483/1256452) is correct, but to go into a little more depth, the "normal" (but optimized) process for a `git push [remote [refspecs ...]]` goes something like this.  We'll anthropomorphize your computer<sup>1</sup>/git-push-process and call it "Bob", and also the remote in question, "Rem".  The exchange goes like this:

BOB: "Hi, I have some branch refspecs for you, what do you have?"

REM: "I've got `master`, `deploy`, `develop`, and `test`."

BOB: "OK, so I've got commit `cabfa4e` as the head of `develop` and `fedcafe` as the head of `test` and I'd like to send you what you need."

REM: "Well I'm already on `fedcafe` on `test` but I have `badf00d` on `develop`..."

BOB: "Ah, well, I see `badf00d` here, I'll give you these new commits and tree/blob/tag objects [hands over long list of object data, packed up as a "thin" pack]."

REM: [pauses to digest the pack, run various hooks, verify that what Bob is giving him is OK and that it's OK to update `develop`; if all goes well] "Thanks Bob!"

BOB: "OK bye, see ya later!"

(When this conversation is over, Bob knows that Rem-the-remote is now on `cabfa4e` on branch `develop`, so Bob updates `remotes/rem/develop` too.)

The point to all this is that Bob and Rem don't know, or even care, *how* they got into the state they were in when they exchanged data and Bob sent over new git-objects (commits, trees, blobs, and/or annotated tags).  When they are done, Rem has whatever Bob sent, and if he "took" it (did not "reject" a reference update), Bob updates his record of what Rem has.

Just as important, Bob simply gives Rem the refspecs.

Let's say you decide to "rewind" ("remove") one or more commits, going from `cabfa4e` back to `badf00d`, and do a force-push.  The conversation is a bit shorter—Rem already has all the objects—and there's a much greater chance Rem will say "nope, no can do, because I don't rewind commits".  Bob will tell Rem that you asked for the push to be "forced" (Rem can still say "no" but the "built in default" is "not unless force", and you asked for "force").

Or, let's say you did *not* decide to rewind anything, but Rem had picked up new commits from Jan earlier, and you don't have them on your computer Bob.  Rem now has `develop` at commit `c0ffeee`, which Bob does not have at all.  Their earliest synchronization point is (still) at `badf00d`.  Bob can propose to Rem: "Let's set `develop` to `cabfa4e` anyway, I'll give you everything from `badf00d` up through `cabfa4e`."  Rem will say "No, you're missing something (i.e., that's not a fast-forward).  I won't do that unless you say force."  It's up to you to fetch-and-(merge/rebase), updating Bob to have `c0ffeee` (and maybe other commits as well).

It's all about the commit graphs.  You (via Bob) propose to the remote (Rem) to change some parts of Rem's commit-graph by changing `refs/heads/` labels to point to different commits; and you (Bob) provide the new parts of the graph, plus any other objects required; and then the remote (Rem) says "OK" or "not OK" according to Rem's rules (hooks).  The default, built-in rule is: "Yes if the `refs/heads/` label moves in a fast-forward fashion.  Otherwise, yes if force, no if not force."

---

<sup>1</sup>"Don't anthropomorphize computers; they hate that."

Comment: nice expansion on my answer

Answer (score 1):

`git push` attempts to update the remote repository to the same state as the local branch that you are pushing.  So any commits that are in that branch will be added to the remote provided that the histories are compatible.  You are not pushing a single commit but rather the state of the entire branch.

Comment: but after a rebase the previous commits (e.g. squashed) are not in the branch anymore... right?

Comment: @JohnRumpel Rebase does not necessary squash commits, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @JohnRumpel squashing changes multiple commits into one.  So if you are asking if the multiple commits are still on the branch, no they are not.  The changes are in one new commit.  The commits on the branch are all the ones that you see with `git log`.  If they ain't in the log, they ain't on the branch.

Comment: @Schleis: Well, this is for squashing and amending. And thus, there is no "fragment" of the commit with an old commit message pushed to the server when rewording the msg since it is a new commit, right? And as I understand, the once backup of the history can be found in your repository. Great. Thanks a lot

Comment: @JohnRumpel: yes, when you do a `rebase`, in general what you're doing is copying (some or all parts of) old commits(s) into new commit(s).  If you had `...--old--A--B` and you "squash" commits A+B that add two different things, you get a new commit `C` that adds two different things at once, `...--old--C` (`A` and `B` are still in your repo but hidden/eventually-garbage-collected, and not "on the branch").    If you, e.g., had `old--A--B--D` and you amend D you get `old--A--B--E`.  Squash A+B and amend D?  Now you go from `old--A--B--D` to `old--C--E`.